# Position: sticky rendering bug in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, rendering, sticky

I am having a problem with a seemingly simple series of slides that use 'position: sticky;' CSS.

You can view the page [here](https://contentaware.surf/sticky3/keikimogradient.html).

On my version of Chrome (86.0.4240.198 for Mac) the slides disappear before I am able to reach the bottom (after the slide "A FINAL POSTING AND A FINAL RESTING PLACE OF SORTS." everything turns black and no further slides are visible - it doesn't seem to render anything after that point).

This bug only seems to occur when viewing through Chrome in full-screen mode - when the browser window is resized the scrolling and sticky effect works as expected. The sticky position also works fine on Safari and Firefox irrespective of screen size. Through a process of trial and error the CSS elements that seem to be affecting things are the linear-gradient background and the border (when these are quoted out the page works fine) - however, I would ideally like to use these if possible.

Any ideas on a fix gratefully received!

Here is the HTML and CSS in case it might be useful:

```
<html>

<head>

<style>

body {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  width: 90%;
}

.slide1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 5vw;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    /*background-color: grey;*/
    font-style: italic;
    color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.15vw red;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, lightblue, blue);
    border: 0.15vw red solid;
}

.slide2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 5vw;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    /*background-color: white;*/
    color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.15vw red;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, lightblue, blue);
    border: 0.15vw red solid;
}


</style>
</head>


<body>


<div class="slide1">
<p>I honestly don't know why I'm writing this - as no one will probably ever read this.</p>
</div>

<div class="slide2">
<p>Probably because I'm angry.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide1">
<p>No, that's not quite right.</p>
</div>

<div class="slide2">
<p>I'm angry at Yahoo! but I'm also sad and melancholy.</p>
</div>

<div class="slide1">
<p>But the funeral isn't just for Geocities, it's for the person I used to be.</p>
</div>

<div class="slide2">
<p>The person who was Keikimo.</p>
</div>

<div class="slide1">
<p>This site was my first website, created many, many eons ago.</p>
</div>

<div class="slide2">
<p>Since then, many things about me have changed.</p>
</div>

<div class="slide1">
<p>I've grown up, graduated from High School,</p>
</div>

<div class="slide2">
<p>graduated from University,</p>
</div>

<div class="slide1">
<p>got a job and moved into the adult world.</p>
</div>

<div class="slide2">
<p>I've gone through 3 computers and 5 hard drives,</p>
</div>

<div class="slide1">
<p>17 notebooks, 3 binders full of looseleaf paper</p>
</div>

<div class="slide2">
<p>and many other assorted hastily jotted scribbles on pieces of paper.</p>
</div>

<div class="slide1">
<p>I'm a much different person now than the one who started this site.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide2">
<p>But through it all, this site has been here,</p>
</div>


<div class="slide1">
<p>a reminder of who I was and where I've come from.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide2">
<p>It was more than just a collection of my writing,</p>
</div>


<div class="slide1">
  <p>more than just another fanpage</p>
</div>


<div class="slide2">
  <p>and much more than just another lousy webpage from the 1990s.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide1">
  <p>The places I linked, the places that linked to me, it's all old history.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide2">
  <p>But it's my history,</p>
</div>


<div class="slide1">
  <p>a piece of me.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide2">
  <p>Over the years I've continued writing,</p>
</div>


<div class="slide1">
  <p>I've learned a lot more about websites</p>
</div>


<div class="slide2">
  <p>and have many other homes under many other names.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide1">
  <p>So it's probably a good time to put Keikimo away for good.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide2">
  <p>A final posting and a final resting place of sorts.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide1">
  <p>So to anyone out there reading this - thanks.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide2">
  <p>Thanks for visiting!</p>
</div>


<div class="slide1">
  <p>Thanks for listening.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide2">
  <p>Thanks for the memories.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide1">
  <p>Thank you for being there for 12 years.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide2">
  <p>It's been a blast!</p>
</div>


<div class="slide1">
  <p>RIP Geocities.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide2">
  <p>RIP Keikimo.</p>
</div>


<div class="slide1">
  <p>1997 - 2009.</p>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Many thanks

Comment: I cannot help you unless you add in your html code.

Comment: Just added the full code now

Comment: It renders OK right to the bottom in Chrome on WIndows10 and Chrome on IOS 14 so looks as though it's MacOS specific.

Answer (score 1):

I can't recreate this issue because I'm on Windows, but if you found a bug you can report it: [Report an issue or send feedback on Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315) (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)

You will need to add a screenshot, description of the bug, check "send system information", and click send.

I tried the page on Windows Chrome Version 87.0.4280.66 (Official Build) (64-bit) and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel you are not really achieving what you want or you have found a bug on the browser you can:

- search for a bug issue on chrome and wait for it to be fixed
- if there's no issue just create one

but most importantly you can simulate the `sticky` positioning with vanilla javascript and the intersection observer. don't just the onscroll event handler, it will kill your performance!

I have created an article explaining how to go about that if you find it suitable [here](https://dioxmio.medium.com/sticky-done-the-right-way-880af0122a71)